# Twilio X Monday.com: Is it possible to insert my Twilio flow when creating my automation on Monday.com in the "SMS MESSAGE" section?

Tags: twilio

I'd like to know how to create an automation on monday.com with a twilio flow (already created).

Because when I want to create an automation on monday I program my automation like this: "1 day before INTERVIEW arrives --> Then Send Twilio SMS MESSAGE from SENDER to RECIPIENT".

And at "SMS MESSAGE" I'd like the flow created in studio to intervene instead of writing an sms

["SMS MESSAGE" automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3ki6.png)

I already have my twilio flow now I'm looking to connect it to my monday.com to create a custom automation with my tables.